# How to multiply a cell when 2 other cells contain value?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a cell which contains a number (C7). I have two other cells that also contain numbers (C9 & C10). If BOTH C9 and C10 contains any number that is not 0, I need C7 to be multiplied by 2.

I can't figure out how to write a formula for this for not being blank and greater than zero. If only one cell is filled in I need it not to multiple it at all, or at the very least just multiply by 1. Thank you!

I am using Excel 2016 on a PC.

****EDIT
Okay that works perfectly but I realize I'm an idiot and I need to include cells C11 and C12 as well and actually make it so C7 is multiplied by the cells with value so if 3 are not empty I need C7*3!

Comment: Okay that works perfectly but I realize I'm an idiot and I need to include cells C11 and C12 as well and actually make it so C7 is multiplied by the cells with value so if 3 are not empty I need C7*3!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be of use: =IF(AND(C9<>0,C10<>0),C7*2,0)
For your edited question you could maybe use =C7*COUNTIF(C9:C12,"<>0")

Comment: Okay that works perfectly but I realize I'm an idiot and I need to include cells C11 and C12 as well and actually make it so C7 is multiplied by the cells with value so if 3 are not empty I need C7*3! Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an if statement in the cell you want the answer.

=IF(AND(C9<>0,C10<>0),C7*2,C7)